# Good format for storing GList in binary file so that text editor won't recognize values of text fields

Tags: c, file-io, glib

I have a GSList which stores structures. When I save it to binary file using the "wb" option of fopen(), everything is ok except that any text editor easily recognizes the values of text fields from structure and displays them correctly. Is there any way to store structures so that text editors won't be able to recognize the text fields. Thanx

Comment: Encrypt the data. On Unix/Linux systems, there is no difference between "w" and "wb"; even on Windows where there is a difference, "b" does not mean "make this file mysteriously unreadable". It only affects the handling of line endings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just want to encode the data somehow.  The easiest would probably be just XORing a the input with a fixed value, then XOR it again when reading.  That said, you probably shouldn't be worrying about it… nobody else does (try running [`strings`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strings) on pretty much anything, you'll see).